# Increase the date of a SWT Datetime automatically

Tags: java, datetime, swt

In my program I have two `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime` widgets. If the one is changed (day, month or year) the other one should be set to the same date increased by two days.

For example the one is set to `01.01.2014` the other one should jump to `03.01.2014`.

Is there any solution, or do you know any snippets about that? I don't want to check always if the first `DateTime` is set to the end of a month, so that the second one should jump to `01.02.2014` or `02.02.2014`...

I hope you understand what I am searching for ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Calendar` and in particular the method `add(int, int)` to add two to `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`. It will move to the next month/year automatically:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    final DateTime first = new DateTime(shell, SWT.CALENDAR);
    final DateTime second = new DateTime(shell, SWT.CALENDAR);

    first.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, first.getYear());
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, first.getMonth());
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, first.getDay());

            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);

            second.setDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.Calendar`:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
```